# How to resolve TypeError: Drupal\Core\Field\FieldTypeCategory::getDescription()

Tags: 10, upgrading

I updated Drupal core to 10.2.0 yesterday. For reference, I am using the commerce module version 2.32. After the update, I am unable to create a new field (Commerce->Configuration->Order Item Types->Manage Fields->Create New Field). I receive the following error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.
>
> TypeError: Drupal\Core\Field\FieldTypeCategory::getDescription(): Return value must be of type Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup, string returned in Drupal\Core\Field\FieldTypeCategory->getDescription() (line 26 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldTypeCategory.php).
> Drupal\field_ui\Form\FieldStorageAddForm->buildForm()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 536)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm() (Line: 283)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (Line: 73)
> Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 627)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 121)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 181)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 76)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 36)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle() (Line: 51)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 704)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

I found the same issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/bibleref/issues/3409299), but this is specific to the bibleref module which I do not have installed. The same error arises if I try to create a new field for any content type. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is caused by https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3409413

Comment: Thanks, the patch resolved the issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug in Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal core 10.2.0 throws this for any field type that does not have a "description" in its definition. As @clifen noted, this is what [this core issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3409413) is about.

It is fixed in drupal/core 10.2.1.

Comment: Yes, update to 10.2.1.